# Passing values from a Slider widget into firestore database

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-widget

I want to know what methods I can use to pass values from slider widget into a function linked to a firestore database. I have a list of values set to zero and the goal is to get the values to change when the slider's value is changed. Here is a snippet of the function:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:wequilschool_app/screens/blend_&_mix/item.dart';

class SaveIngredientsProvider {
  /// Firestore database reference to the BlendandMix collection
  final CollectionReference blendAndMixDatabase =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("BlendandMix");

  /// Stores the item's objects
  List<Item> item = [];

  Future<void> updateIngredientCount() {

    // ignore: avoid_dynamic_calls
    return blendAndMixDatabase
        .doc('H2IbznvLGKYRvCLJSomk')
        .set({
          'ingredients': {
            'almond_butter': 0,
            'bananas': 0,
            'blackberries': 0,
            'blueberries': 0,
            'chia_seeds': 0,
            'chocolate_protein_powder': 0,
            'flax_seeds': 0,
            'greek_yogurt': 0,
            'ice_cubes': 0,
            'mango_chunks': 0,
            'mint': 0,
            'pineapple_chunks': 0,
            'raspberries': 0,
            'strawberries': 0,
            'vanilla_protein_powder': 0
          },
        }, SetOptions(merge: true))
        .then((value) => print("Ingrdient(s) Number Updated"))
        .catchError(
            (error) => print("Failed to update ingredient count: $error"));
  }
}
```

Here is another snippet with the Slider widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:wequilschool_app/screens/blend_&_mix/services/save_ingredients_provider.dart';

/// Smoothie ingredient item

class Item extends StatefulWidget {
  final String image;
  final String name;
  double saveValue = 0.0;
  double? defaultSaveValue = 0.0;

  /// Each item needs an image and name, so it is required
  Item({
    Key? key,
    required this.image,
    required this.name,
    this.defaultSaveValue,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ItemState createState() => _ItemState();
}

class _ItemState extends State<Item> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Image.asset(
          widget.image,
          width: 70,
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Text("${widget.name}", textAlign: TextAlign.center),
        ),
        Expanded(
            child: Slider(
          value: widget.defaultSaveValue ?? widget.saveValue,
          min: 0,
          max: 5,
          divisions: 5,
          label: widget.saveValue.toString(),
          onChanged: (double newValue) {
            setState(() {
              widget.defaultSaveValue = newValue;
              widget.saveValue = newValue;
            });
          },
        )),
        ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              SaveIngredientsProvider().updateIngredientCount();
            },
            child: const Text('Save Ingredients')),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call the firestore function inside the `onChangedEnd()` method of slider.  So when the value of your slider change ends, it will set the value in the firestore.
Pass the slider's value in firestore function to correctly set the value in DB.

Comment: @ChineduNwabuisi Please let us know if the above answer helps you?

Comment: Does this [answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)? Please consider accepting the answer to make it more visible for the community members.